# Highcharts - Legends overlapping chart area

Tags: highcharts

My legends are overlapping the chart area
I am trying to plot the legends on left of the chart. Margin-left, Spacing-left not worked.

[Legends overlapping issue in highcharts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L4ix.png)

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tLomq3sa/

```
 "legend": {
        "enabled": true,
        "maxHeight": 350,
        "floating": false,
        "width": 400,
        "symbolWidth": 11,
        "symbolHeight": 11,
        "align": "left",
        "verticalAlign": "middle",
        "padding": 30,
        "itemStyle": {
            "width": 110,
            "fontSize": "16",
            "margin-right": 200
        }
    },
 "chart": {
        "marginRight": 0,
        "marginLeft": 50,
        "spacingBottom": 0,
        "type": "column",
        "height": null,
        "width": null,
        "options3d": {
            "enabled": true,
            "alpha": 8,
            "beta": 20,
            "viewDistance": 30
        },
        "events": {},
        "spacingLeft": 100
    },
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `verticalAlign: 'middle'` in combination with `align: 'left'` then `chart.marginLeft` should not be set to a static value because the chart then does not automatically calculate the width for the legend.

```js
...
chart: {
  marginRight: 0,
  //marginLeft: 50,
  ...
},
...
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/89t5bu0m/

Comment: Thanks @Michał It worked perfectly. Cheers!